# Overwrite Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown Menu Colors with LESS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I don't find a way to use custom background colors for both the dropdown-toggle and the dropdown-menu of a Bootstrap sidebar with LESS CSS. It all works fine in pure CSS, but when using LESS, I can't get it to work. What I want to achieve is something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/GqVM2/6/

My LESS code for that bit is here:

```
.navbar-default {
  .navbar-nav {
    > open {
      > a,
      > a:hover,
      > a:focus {
        @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
          background-color: #aaaaaa;
        }
      }
      > .dropdown-menu {
        @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
          background-color: #aaaaaa;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above code does not override the Bootstrap LESS as (I suppose) it should. With the CSS I used in the JSFiddle, it works fine though.

I'm pretty new to LESS, so excuse me if this is just a stupid mistake. When I inspect the generated CSS in the Chrome Developer Tools, the above does not even show up (I'm using the LESS JavaScript parser for development).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It doesn't sound like your LESS is getting compiled correctly, if you say you aren't seeing your changes reflected in the generated output (CSS).

Answer (score 0):

**First:** you have mispelled an selector.... `open` should be `.open`:

```
.navbar-default {
  .navbar-nav {
    > open { // here it's the problem!
      > a,
      > a:hover,
      > a:focus {
        @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
          background-color: #aaaaaa;
        }
      }
      > .dropdown-menu {
        @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
          background-color: #aaaaaa;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Secondly:** there are better ways of customizing Bootstrap. They have lots of variables that allow you to easily change how your build will look like. And the navbar dropdown is no exception.

You can customize it by changing the variables `@navbar-default-link-active-bg` and `@navbar-default-link-active-color`.